# Identifying date columns in pandas while reading through csv

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I'm working on this [dataset](http://www.ldeo.columbia.edu/%7Erpa/usgs_earthquakes_2014.csv). I want to read the data in such a way that all date columns are identified as dates.
I'm new to pandas so this might be quite a silly one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one way:

```
import pandas as pd
​
filename = 'https://www.ldeo.columbia.edu/~rpa/usgs_earthquakes_2014.csv'
​
df = pd.read_csv(filename, parse_dates=['time', 'updated'])
​
df.dtypes

time              datetime64[ns]
latitude                 float64
longitude                float64
depth                    float64
mag                      float64
magType                   object
nst                      float64
gap                      float64
dmin                     float64
rms                      float64
net                       object
id                        object
updated      datetime64[ns, UTC]
place                     object
type                      object
dtype: object
```